# Why is the shear stress in newtonian fluids proportional to the gradient of velocity?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, fluid-dynamics, viscosity

Why is the shear stress in newtonian fluids proportional to the gradient of velocity in the direction perpendicular to the flow?

I watched several videos which all explain the example with the two plates with water between them, where one is moving at constant speed and the other not.

$τ=μ\frac{∂u}{∂y}$

I can follow how they derive it, but they don't explain the background why the inner friction (and therefore the force required to move a plate) increases with velocity. In the end it's always written that it was found out in experiments.

I think what I'm missing is the part about viscosity and how the momentum is transferred.

What is the reason the friction increases with speed (opposed to solid bodies)? Are there any ressources explaining the backgrounds and not only referring to experiments?